# MySql select Mix and Max year

Tags: mysql

Hi guys I am developing a php and mysql application. I want to select Min and Max from year. It should show correct year like below:

```
Min = 1998
Max = 2014
```

My table structure like below

### Table: Students

```
year varchar(32)    utf8_unicode_ci 
-------------------------------
06-04-2012
02-05-2014
19-04-1999
05-05-2014
06-04-1998
```

I try to use MySql Min and Max but not working well.

```
SELECT MIN(`year`) AS Year FROM `Students`

SELECT Max(`year`) AS Year FROM `Students`
```

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: Store dates as dates. Do NOT try to hack together some pointless, slow, and ineffiicient workaround. Fixing structural problems now will pay dividends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not store dates as strings.  You should store them as dates.

But, because you have this format, you can use the `right()` function to get the year:

```
select min(right(year, 4)), max(right(year, 4))
from students;
```

If, for some unfathomable reason, you do have to store dates as strings, then use the ISO standard YYYY-MM-DD format.

If you want the minimum of the entire values as a date, then convert it to a date:

```
select min(str_to_date(year, '%d-%m-%Y')), max(str_to_date(year, '%d-%m-%Y'))
from students;
```

But, you should be storing the date using the proper data type in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`YEAR()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) function rather like

```
SELECT MIN(YEAR(`year`)) AS Year FROM `Students`
```